# How to reform a expression to improve numerical stability?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, signal-processing

In engineering, we usually have to solve a function numerically, which has no symbolic computation ability and may using a low percision data type like `fp32` or even `fp16`.
Hence, we have to reform a function expression to avoid division by a small number, or remove discontinuities, to improve numerical stability on more condition.
For example, we can reform $$\frac{\frac{1}{t^2}-1}{(t+\frac{1}{t})^2}$$ to $$\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}$$ so we have definition when `x == 0` and better numerical stability when `t` is small.

## How can I do this work by Mathematica automatically?

For example, I have a function, which is unstable for low precision data types when `f->0` and `f->1`, and hard to reform manually: $$g(f)=-\frac{i-ie^{-2if\pi}}{4f\pi-4f^3\pi},(f\geq0)$$ Obviously $$\lim_{f\rightarrow0}g(f)=\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$\lim_{f\rightarrow1}g(f)=-\frac{1}{4}$$ How can I reform it by Mathematica to remove the discontinuities at `f == 0` and `f == 1`, and prevent the small number division if possible?

Comment: I want to reform the function expression and solve it numerically in my enginnering program, which has no symbolic computation ability.

Comment: Then you should really mention this in the question itself to be more clear. All what you have to do for the example you have is `Simplify[expr]` which will give you what you wanted.

Comment: @Nasser The `Simplify[expr]` function give me the original expression, which has discontinuities.

Comment: Instead of using the original function `g[v_] := I/(4 \[Pi] v) (1 - Exp[2 \[Pi] I v])/(1 - v^2)` use its Taylor series with an appropriate lenght, e.g. `Series[g[v], {v, 1/2, 6}] // Normal` in the whole region.

Comment: @Artes Thanks for your comment. `Series[g[v], {v, 0, 10}]` gives out a more simpiler result which satisfied the percision requirement. But it's still more slower than the original expression. Is there a better way than seris?

Comment: Perhps you could exploit  `PadeApproximant`, however it depends on specific aspects of your problem. If you use `Series` remember to evaluate with `Normal` in order to get an ordinary expression.

Comment: E.g. `PadeApproximant[g[v], {v, 0, {3, 4}}] // N` yields `(0.5 + (0. + 0.298574 I) v - 
 0.154029 v^2 - (0. + 0.0344845 I) v^3)/(1. - (0. + 2.54445 I) v - 
 2.72193 v^2 + (0. + 1.47873 I) v^3 + 0.354081 v^4)`.  You have to play around a bit to decide what would be the most efficient way and simultaneously well approximated.

Comment: You might also want to consider to use Taylor or Padé approximations only in small intervals of the problematic points. That will take you several branching constructs like (`Piecewise` is particularly useful for that within _Mathematica_, but in general you might have to use `if`s or other `switch`s). You also have to fiddle around with parameters for the expansion order and the diameter of the intervals, but that can be figured out by running test in _Mathematica_...

Comment: Once you have found a nice polynomial, you might want to apply `HornerForm` to it in order to make its evaluation both more efficient and more stable.